# How to return an observable method in another observable Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular7

In component service class override base-service get method using angular7. I want return mapped data if need to map data, else return origin data. This is my function:

```
read(isSelectable:boolean): Observable<IFailureMode> {
  const observable = new Observable<IFailureMode>(subscriber => {
      if (isSelectable) {
        return super.read(filter).subscribe(data=>mapToSelectableModel(data));// Here want to return mapped data
      } else {
        return super.read(filter);//Here want to return origin data
      }
    });
  return observable;
}
```

How can return super.read(filter) as observable.next? Is there more useful method for do it?

Comment: So, you want to convert `filter` to a stream of `super.read`s, which are mapped conditionally?

Comment: could you be looking for [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) or [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from)?

Comment: @ThorJacobsen I want check filter option to mapping or not data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected answer**

If all you want is to apply a mapping to `super.read` depending on a provided argument, this should do it:

```
read(isSelectable) {
  return super.read(filter)
    .pipe(map(data => isSelectable ? mapToSelectableModel(data) : data));
}
```

**Original answer (incorrect)**

If I understand your question correctly, this would be an approach for you:

```
read(fitler) {
  return of(filter)
    .pipe(
      map(f => {
        if (f.key === 'isSelectable' && f.value === 'true') {
          return super.read(f).pipe(map(data => mapToSelectableModel(data));
        } else {
          return super.read(f);
        }
      })
    );
}
```

In this case, the `super` call will be mapped conditionally